# How to convert WebGrid column's int value to string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, webgrid

I am using `WebGrid` to display data from Model. I want that ID column should be hyperlink. So, when anyone click on ID,it's corresponding page will be open. I have tried following code, but I am getting error:  `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'`

**CODE:**

```
grid.Column(columnName: "ID", header: "ID", canSort: true, format: item => Html.ActionLink((string)item.ID, "../CRM/DetailsRequest", new { ID = item.ID })),....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the ID property is an integer, so you cannot cast it to string. Try casting it to an integer first:

```
grid.Column(
    columnName: "ID", 
    header: "ID", 
    canSort: true, 
    format: item => Html.ActionLink(
        ((int)item.ID).ToString(), 
        "DetailsRequest", 
        "CRM", 
        new { ID = item.ID }, 
        null
    )
)
```

Or if in your view model you had another string property which you would like to use as the anchor text:

```
grid.Column(
    columnName: "ID", 
    header: "ID", 
    canSort: true, 
    format: item => Html.ActionLink(
        (string)item.Name, 
        "DetailsRequest", 
        "CRM", 
        new { ID = item.ID }, 
        null
    )
)
```